# Input of next line separated numbers in list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm taking input from a standard input stream as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to take the whole line separated input in a list and to print it as

```
 ['1','2','3','4','5','6'].
```

Comment: so you want call ``input()`` six times? and what does **I want this in a list or as a string** mean?

Comment: rather than calling  `input()` six times, do we have any other method to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

use `sys.stdin.read()` for Multi-line input:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
data_list = data.strip().split('\n')
```

Comment: What's the need of a list if you use variables for individuals?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque  use variables for individuals? What do you mean?

Comment: variables for individual input? Isn't it funny that first you are defining bunch of variable and then print it forming a list. Plus, this is not a generalized solution.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque Hum...All right, I think you're right. But I don't know how to optimize it. Any ideas?

Comment: See my answer, though this works for fixed input, but op doesn't want that

Comment: @AhsanulHaque thanks, I think OP wants the first solution.  Let me delete the second one.

Answer (score 0):

And i had done the same as below:

```
import sys
arr = sys.stdin.read()
list = data.splitlines()
```

Comment: See the built-in [str.splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fixed number of input, do it in a for loop.

```
lst=[]
for i in range(6):
    lst.append(input())

print lst
```

To launch the process forever until `KeyboardInterrupt`, you can do this:

```
lst=[]
while True:
    lst.append(input())
    print lst
```

You can also use `signal` if want to do something after `ctl`+`c`

```
import signal
import sys
def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print lst
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

lst=[]
while(True):
    lst.append(input())
```

If you want to input until a particular character for example `space` input:

```
lst=[]
while True:
    demo = raw_input()
    if demo==" ":
        break
    lst.append(demo)

print lst
```

Comment: No, length of the number of input is unknown

Comment: @AthulRaj, when will input end? a keyboard interrupt?

Answer (score -1):

For string:

```
My_String = ""
a = input()
while a  != "":
    My_String += a
    a = input()
return My_String
```

For list

```
My_List = []
a = input()
while a  != "":
    My_List.append(a)
    a = input()
return My_List
```